# The assignment in Verilog

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment

Why does the Verilog simulator handle these cases differently?

1)

```
always  #1 clk =! clk;
initial
begin
@(posedge clk)
start <= 1;
end
```

2. 

```
initial
begin
clk <= 1;
start <= 1;
end
```

The literature says that in 1 case, the clk and start signals will be set simultaneously and clk can capture the start signal only on the next edge. That's how it works.

But why is the second case different from the first? After all, nonblocking assignments should also be set at the same time. But it doesn't work as in the first case. But if you write it like that, then it works like the first case.

2)

```
initial
begin
clk = 1;
start <= 1;
end
```

Example
1)

```
module test();
reg clk=0;
reg start=0;
reg flag=0;

always  #1 clk =! clk;

initial
begin
#5;
@(posedge clk)
start <= 1;
end

always@(posedge clk)
if(start)
  flag<=1;

endmodule
```

2. 

```
module test();
reg clk=0;
reg start=0;
reg flag=0;


initial
begin
#5;
clk <= 1;
start <= 1;
end

always@(posedge clk)
if(start)
  flag<=1;

endmodule
```

Simulation results

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W2eyKEXLEfwpB_iIfGnSzHqfSOw1Vs_M/view?usp=sharing]

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17F9NIH41DKhrvJqnQTG7jPkfcNoJjBfh/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code examples do not follow recommended coding style for synchronous logic.  This leads to simulation race conditions.

You should expect different results with these different code samples.

You are mixing coding styles.  You should generate the clock with the blocking assignment (`=`) in an `always` block.  Since `start` and `flag` are synchronous to `clk`, they should both use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) and be aligned with the clock (`@(posedge clk)`):

```
module test();
reg clk=0;
reg start=0;
reg flag=0;

always #1 clk = !clk;

initial
begin
    repeat (3) @(posedge clk);
    start <= 1;
end

always @(posedge clk)
    if (start) flag <= 1;
endmodule
```